# Google Cloud Messaging: Payload value always string

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on integrating goggle cloud messaging for one of my app. 
From server, I am sending key value pair as:

```
'not_id'       => 1000,
'title'         => 'This is a title. title',
'vibrate'   => 1,
'sound'     => 1
```

In android GCMIntentService:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  

        int not_id=extras.getInt("not_id");
```

While extracting the value of key not_id(which is a integer), following exceptions are thrown:

> Key not_id expected Integer but value was a
>   java.lang.String.java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot
>   be cast to java.lang.Integer

Does gcm converts all value to String?

Went through the docs, in vain. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I have the same problem.

Comment: No. I didn't spend much time on this as I didn't get proper response even from S.O. Assumed that, gcm always returns string, used type cast in my code with ClassCastException exception handling... Weird isn't it? GCM should have preserve the type.. Would have made life little easier

Comment: Ya I  guess it converts everything to String. But i figured out a solution. I stringified and inserted the whole json payload as a key value pair inside 'data' key of the gcm. Then my payload is received as a json properly.

Comment: Nice.. Can you please post it as an answer. Someone might find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem. The workaround I found is to stringify the json we create and add that whole json as a key values pair in the data object which we send to the gcm cloud server -

Normally what we send -

```
myData: {
          'title' : 'New Notification',
          'myAge' : 25
    }
json: {
        'to': to,
        'data': myData
    }
```

This way all the values inside the data bundle are converted to String. In the above data 25 is converted to String.

The way I do it -

```
json: {
        'to': to,
        'data': {'myData' : myData}
    }
```

Now 25 will remain an Integer .

**Note** - Stringify the myData JsonObject before sending it. In Javascript I use `JSON.stringify(myData);`

Then at the Android end we can retrieve the whole json -

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    try {
        JSONObject myData = new JSONObject(data.getString("myData"));
    } catch (JSONException e){}
}
```

Now all the values retrieved will be in their original types.

Comment: This one is better than typecasting catching ClassCastException. So far to me, this looks a better work-around. Accepting..